# How to Prevent Map from Mutating Data in Javascript

Tags: javascript, list, immutability

I have an object array that looks like this:

```
rawData:
0: {name: "cat", count: 2}
1: {name: "dog", count: 5}
2: {name: "fish", count: 3}
```

and I have a translatedData that multiplies the count field by 2.

```
newData:
0: {name: "cat", count: 4}
1: {name: "dog", count: 10}
2: {name: "fish", count: 6}
```

I use the following calculation:

```
let newData = Object.assign({}, rawData);

newData = Object.keys(newData).map(key => {
  let newValue = Math.round(newData[key].all*2);
  newData[key].all = newValue;
  return newData[key];
});
```

I use a map to perform this calculation. My issue is when when I console.log both these arrays they both have the calculation. I want the rawData to have its previous state and not be affected by the calculation.I thought object.assign would fix this. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: There is no `all` property in the data you have shown?

Comment: `return Object.assign({}, newData[key], { all: newData[key].all * 2 })` from within the `.map`.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comment, the problem is you haven't performed a deep clone. You could go that route, but a simpler (and more typical) solution is to just construct the new object manually, in the map call.

```
newData = rawData.map(({name, count}) => ({name, count: count * 2})
```

If the data is actually highly nested and this is just an simplified example, the deep clone option might be better.

The above is assuming your object is an `Array`.

Comment: `map` is array method, not available on objects.

Comment: @Clarity According to OP, `oldData` should be an array.

Comment: I only see `rawData` there.

Comment: @Clarity Same thing.